# Blank Content in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I try figuring out how to have a blank content in Drupal, no theme, no header...etc. Which approach should I use? Create a new theme? Create a new view? Install a suitable modules? What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you just want you content to be printed without any styles around it.

You could make a theme and strip the html.tpl.php, page.tpl.php and node.tpl.php files.

In addition i think you could make theme functions in you template file to remove all the html around fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achievable using **pure CSS and Responsive Design** principles. A nice concise definition of Responsive Design is:

> "Responsive design is an approach to web page creation that makes use
>   of flexible layouts, flexible images and cascading style sheet media
>   queries.  The goal of responsive design is to build web pages that
>   detect the visitor’s screen size and orientation and change the layout
>   accordingly." [Source](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/responsive-design)

[This article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/05/17/responsive-web-design-ideas-technology-and-examples/) is less than two months old and not only covers the principles, but gives examples and has links to tutorials.

So, the solution is: figure out when you want this bare display used, and create a CSS that will hide all of those elements using `display:none;`.